# How does "ImageReader.getSurface()" work?

Tags: android, android-image, image-reader

I am working with the camera2 API in android and am trying to understand this code I am using. Part of the code goes like this:

```
previewReader = ImageReader.newInstance(previewSize.getWidth(), previewSize.getHeight(), 
                                        ImageFormat.YUV_420_888, 4);

previewReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(imageListener, backgroundHandler);
// This adds another output surface but not sure where this surface comes from..
previewRequestBuilder.addTarget(previewReader.getSurface());
```

`imageListener` is an object from another class that implements `android.media.ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener` and `backgroundHandler` is just a background thread. I am not including code for these two or `previewRequestBuilder` as they do not seem to be important for understanding my question.

I have searched extensively but it just seems like some magic happens and `previewReader` finds some surface somewhere, somehow. According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/media/ImageReader#getsurface), what `getSurface()` does is to:

> Get a `Surface` that can be used to produce `Image` for this `ImageReader`

Can anyone explain where it gets this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That `Surface` belongs to the `ImageReader`; it was created in the native equivalent of the `ImageReader's` constructor, and is (effectively) an `ImageReader` private member, with a getter.

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/jni/android_media_ImageReader.cpp#377) is the line in the native constructor that sets up the `IGraphicBufferProducer` (`gbProducer`), which is basically the native equivalent of a `Surface`.

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/media/jni/android_media_ImageReader.cpp#685) is where you can see that the native code uses that same member to form the return value from `getSurface()/nativeGetSurface()` (you may have to trace through the code a bit, but it's all there).

So that's the literal answer to your question. But maybe you were asking because it isn't clear why the camera doesn't create the `Surface`, and force you to give it to the `ImageReader`, instead: A `Surface` is a complex object (actually, a buffer queue), and shouldn't be thought of as a simple, pre-allocated bitmap. At the time the capture takes place, the camera pipeline will communicate with its output `Surfaces`, and set up the correct dimensions and color planes and so forth. (Note that you can add multiple targets via `addTarget()`; the camera can use each of them.) All the camera needs to know is where it's going to send its output; it doesn't need to create the output `Surface` itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's strange because I feel like the Android API has too many things that are not clearly explained. The first part of your answer was what I was looking but the second part offers appreciated extra details!